# Double Integral with uncertain f(x,y)

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I'm having trouble with a double integral problem for an assignment (if possible, hints in the right direction are preferred over straight solutions).
The idea is to find some f(x,y) such that:
$$\iint\limits_Df(x,y)\;dA=\iint\limits_Dx\;f(x,y)\;dA=0,\quad f(1,2)=-1$$
The region $D$ is bounded by $x=0, y=0, x+y=3$
This means: $$D=\{(x,y)\vert\,0\lt x\lt 3, 0\lt y \lt 3-x\}$$
Through trial and error I've been able to find some f(x,y) that satisfies all but the initial condition (that $f(1,2)=-1$). Other than that, I've no idea where to start. Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One clue is to note that each of the three conditions imposes a constraint, so if you choose a functional form for $f(x,y)$ that is simple and contains three parameters, you might be able to obtain a solution that satisfies all the constraints for a suitable choice of parameters.

In particular, suppose we let $$f(x,y) = ax + by + c,$$ which describes a plane.  What relationship between $a, b, c$ is required to satisfy the third condition?  Then, what relationship is required to satisfy the first condition?  And finally, what unique solution results from satisfying the second condition?